# Faltten a list using xlinq (with Yield return)

Tags: linq-to-xml, yield

I have a shot problem...
I have an xml file i'd like to store in a list of element.

I would like to Flatten this list on order to follow another pattern given by another datasource.

here is an xml sample

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>    
   <Actors>
    <Actor FirstName="Will" LastName="Smith">
      <Movie name="Men in Black" Date="1999"/>
      <Movie name="Wild wild west" Date="1999"/>
      <Movie name="Ali" Date="2002"/>
    </Actor>
    <Actor FirstName="Jason" LastName="Statham">
     <Movie name="The Transporter" Date="2002"/>   
     <Movie name="Revolver" Date="2005"/>
     <Movie name="The Bank Job" Date="2008"/>
     <Movie name="Transporter 3" Date="2008"/>
    </Actor> 
 </Actors>
```

Then, I create a my object

```
public class Actors
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

And now, I read this xml with xlinq like this:

```
        private static void Read(string fileName)
    {
        XDocument testDoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
        var reader = from c in testDoc.Root.Elements()
                     select c;


        var list = reader.ToList();



    }
```

Now I would like to fill a List ands for each item, all the data (FirstName, LastName, Name, Date) must be present.

I think Yield return must solve my problem, but actually I don't understand clearly how it works. (and I'd like to implement it)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply want

```
List<Actors> actors = (from movie in XDocument.Load(fileName).Descendants("Movie")
  select new Actors() {
    FirstName = (string)movie.Parent.Attribute("FirstName"),
    LastName = (string)movie.Parent.Attribute("LastName")
    Name = (string)movie.Attribute("name"),
    Date = (string)movie.Attribute("Date")
 }).ToList();
```

Comment: it looks pretty good, but I don't know for whatever reason, I'm not able to filter any node. The xxx.Descendants("Movie") return always 0... but if If put xxx.Descendants(); I'll recieve my complete list. I use de XDocument.Load(..), Strangely, When I put a value in the attibute, it's taken into account...

Comment: Does the XML have a namespace declaration in the form of e.g. `<Actors xmlns="http://example.com">...</Actors>`? In that case doing e.g. XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml"); XNamespace df = doc.Root.Name.Namespace; List<Actors> actors = (from movie in XDocument.Load(fileName).Descendants(df + "Movie") select new ... ).ToList();` should work.

Comment: Thanks for this reply. Actually yes, there were a namepsace... I included it and now it works

Answer (score 0):

use this query

```
var reader = from a in testDoc.Root.Descendants("Actor")
             from m in a.Descendants("Movie")
             select new Actors
             {
                FirstName = a.Attribute("FirstName").Value,
                LastName = a.Attribute("LastName").Value,
                Name = m.Attribute("name").Value,
                Date = m.Attribute("Date").Value
             };
```